# SectionGroup Footer of AX reoport is not in provided location

Tags: report, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a problem with report, just created a `generated design` and added two `sectionGroups` from which each of `sectionGroup` has 3 sections `(header,body,footer)`.

All the data is working perfectly but when I am running the report, `sectionGroup footer` is placing in wrong location, I just want every `footer` inside it's related `sectionGroup`.

[image: My Report Design]

The Output of above Report:

[image: Output of report]

Maybe there I have more than 10 `sectionGroups`, I want the same design for all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may succeed with using:

```
element.addPendingSums();
```

Call it before printing the second header (before super() in `executeSection`).

Or maybe you need to have the second section group nested in the first body (your data does not look like that).

Comment: Now both `footers` for sectionGroup1 and sectionGroup2 is coming before of second header.
But I want every footer of related sectionGroup must come after it's related body.

Comment: Okay, it was worth a try. You may want suppress calling super() in sectionGroup2 footer by using a boolean variable.

Comment: So, can you help me with some code for you above comment? I didn't catch it clearly. Thanks

Comment: In the line of: `if (sect2) super();` in `executeSection` of sectionGroup2. And `super(); sect2 = true;` in `executeSection` of sectionGroup1.

Comment: Now `footer` for sectionGroup2 is hiden and not appearing. I placed breakpoint and it seems that `if(sec2) super();` is calling first, then it is going to the `executeSection` of sectionGroup1.

Comment: You may have to call `element.addPendingSums();` again after selecting your records. Again purely speculative, as you did not publish source code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58779/discussion-between-khaksar-weqar-and-jan-b-kjeldsen).

Comment: Thanks, finally it worked, added `element.addPendingSums();` for every sectionGroup's body after body's last record, means I counted the records for every body and added `element.addPendingSums();` after counted records loaded into report.